# Проблема с публикацией приложения в Google Play

Tags: android-studio, google-play

У меня проблема с выкладыванием обновления в Google Play. Я писал код в AIDE на телефоне и потом переносил код в студию, компилировал и подписывал, ключ использовал один тот же, с ним проблем нет. Проблема вот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это и почему? Выкладываю с одного ноутбука код переносил и делал так 2 раза сейчас вот эта проблема.

> Добавленные ранее APK-файлы подписаны сертификатами с цифровыми отпечатками
>   [ SHA1: CB:6B:26:9A:FC:69:D1:E4:8A:20:57:B7:C2:C6:66:E0:0D:C9:DA:55 ]
>   , а новый APK-файл – сертификатом с отпечатком
>   [ SHA1: E3:D6:5C:84:4C:E6:E7:8A:4A:10:C5:91:9E:7B:79:D2:4F:74:5E:88 ]
>   . Используйте один и тот же сертификат.

вот мой манифест

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="ru.pareto.pmlanding">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
     <application android:name=".VolleyApplication" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
     <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:label="Вход">
     <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
     <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
     <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
     <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" android:label="Настройки">
     <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
     <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:label="BootReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
     <service android:exported="false" android:name=".NotificationJobService">
     <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE" />
</intent-filter>
</service>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Проблема гигантская так как приложение тестируют и не хотелось бы ничего перезаливать, да и вообще,

Comment: В манифесте скорее всего API key Старого приложения и ново собранного разные!

Comment: @Victor, обновил вопрсс ключей нет никаких

Comment: Не помню уже точно где и как подсовываются ключи для подписи. Или в `gradle` или при билде релиза указывается ключ ! Так вот эти ключи разные!!! Я уже не помню точно, давно подписывал, сейчас более опытные вам подскажут где ключи указываются

Comment: @Victor, хорошо

Comment: Ключи для подписи у вас таки разные, врядли консоль смогла тут ошибиться. Проверьте ещё раз какие файлы-ключи вы использовали для подписи.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а как проверить?

Comment: как можно проверить в какой кейсторе лежит sha 1? не зря же мне пишут какой был

Comment: не тем ключом подписываете. Ищите оригинальный keystore и берите правильный ключ из него

Comment: @Flippy, ну, по идее через файловый менеджер посмотреть на всех машинах что за файлы вы для подписывания использовали и сравнить их. По названиям там, по расширению... Если у вас есть подписывание в скрипте сборки, то можно прямо из студии парой кнопок получить все sha-1 всех ключей

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я добавлял автоподписывание как получить sha1?

Comment: @Flippy, спрва вверху студии есть кнопка Gradle. в ней надо app-Tasks-android-signinReport запустить. В результате выполнения увидите отпечатки всех ключей которыми АПК может быть подписана при сборке

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ничего не появляется! Чтото проходит но ничего не вижу

Comment: @ЮрийСпб, извините, появляется. Результат выполнения посмотрел.  SHA-1 ключ который пишет Google Play Developer Console не вижу. Ключ я не менял, он у меня один. Что происходит вообще не понимаю

Comment: @Flippy, т.е. у вас выводятся отпечатки релизных ключей и при этом ни один из них не совпадает с тем, что говорит консоль?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, именно так я еще раз перепроверил

Comment: @Flippy, в теории такого не может быть. Тут два варианта - либо вы что-то таки где-то не доглядели или глючит сама консоль разработчика. Может попробовать тоже самое завтра с утра?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я нашел еще хранилище ключей его создавал в последний раз я вспомнил выполнил сигнрепорт и получил сха1 как в консоли выкладываюю обновление огромное вам спасиьо!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Консоль не обманывает и вы подписали АПК не тем ключом. Чтобы проверить какими ключами подписывается АПК при сборке вы можете (если у вас настроено подписывание релизным ключом в скрипте сборки) через кнопку Gradle (правый верхний угол студии) в ней надо `app-Tasks-android-signinReport` запустить. В результате выполнения увидите отпечатки всех ключей которыми АПК может быть подписана при сборке.